# Error in string length

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios7

I have a table view which may contain number of data.
When user select one particular cell I set Id in string based on that selection. And then I am trying to find length of that string. But I am getting error in that. When I print that string it print its value.
Here is my code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 NSArray *charityArray = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
charityId=[charityArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"charityId%@",charityId);
NSLog(@"charitylen%d",[charityId length]);
}
```

and here is log screen.

> 2013-12-04 14:47:13.897 GratZeez[2178:a0b] charityId3 
>   2013-12-04 14:47:13.897 GratZeez[2178:a0b] -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd174070 2013-12-04 14:47:13.899
>   GratZeez[2178:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd174070'

declaration of charityId:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface ExsitingCharityViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITextFieldDelegate>
{
NSMutableArray *dataArray,*tempArray,*searchResultArray,*nameSearchArray;
BOOL search;
NSMutableDictionary *dataDict;
CGPoint originalCenter;
NSString *charityId;
 }
```

Comment: Show us code where you add data to this array. This `charityId` is `NSNumber` object, not `NSString`.

Comment: add code for dataArray, where you initialise and add objects to it.

Comment: you can see in my edit that charityId is string

Comment: @vivek: It does not matter how you *declare* the charityId variable. If `[charityArray objectAtIndex:0]` is a NSNumber object then charityId points to that object, it is not magically converted to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code, Convert `NSNumber` to `NSString` and then use `length`

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
           NSArray *charityArray = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           charityId = [charityArray objectAtIndex:0];
           NSString *charityString = [charityId stringValue];
           NSLog(@"charityString = %@", charityString);
           NSLog(@"charityString length = %d",[charityString length]);
    }
```

Comment: because I have posted it according to SO rules...but some people are targeting me and giving downvotes to my every question...now I got banned to asking question

Answer (score 1):

As you post, charityId s not a `NSNumber` formatted type value.
If you want to know to length convert in to `NSString` formate,
Like, `NSString* str = [NSString stringwithFormat:@"%@", charityId];`
then you get `length`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to `NSLog` an `NSNumber` do the following, replace this:

```
NSLog(@"charitylen%d",[charityId length]);
```

With this:

```
NSString *myString = [charityId stringValue];
NSLog(@"charitylen%@", myString);
```

And if you are trying to get the count of your Array use the following:

```
NSLog(@"charitylen%d",[charityId count]);
```

**Update:**

I have to opinions about your case:

1- It means that you are passing an `NSNumber` where the called code expects an `NSString` or some other object that has a `length` method. You can tell Xcode to break on exceptions so that you see where exactly the `length` method gets called.

2-I think it may because your `charityId` is empty or never used before you `NSLog` it .

Comment: It means that you are passing an `NSNumber` where the called code expects an `NSString` or some other object that has a `length` method. You can tell Xcode to break on exceptions so that you see where exactly the `length` method gets called.

Comment: it call when i wrote [charityId length]

Answer (score 0):

As the error log shows, you are sending the length message to a `NSNumber` object. According to your post, you seem to be trying to send it to a `NSString` but it is not a `NSString`.

> -[__**NSCFNumber** length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd174070'

Comment: charityID is, indeed, a `NSString` pointer, but [charityArray objectAtIndex:0] seems to be a `NSNumber`.
If you are wondering why it is possible, just remember that `objectAtIndex:` returns an `id` object, which can thus be assigned to a `NSString` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use the %d string format specifier with an `NSNumber` you should convert the NSNumber object to an integer first:

```
NSLog(@"charityId%d",[charityId intValue]);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code for `NSNumber` to `NSString`

```
NSString *strId=[NSString StringWithFormat@"%d", charityId];
NSLog(@"charitylen%d",[strId length]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` it's mean you are tried to get `length` of a number (i.e. `int`, `NSInteger` etc). so you need to typecast.

you can do it either using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", charityId]` or `[charityId stringValue]`

so just do below

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSArray *charityArray = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   charityId=[charityArray objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *charityIdString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", charityId];
   NSLog(@"charityId%@",charityIdString);
   NSLog(@"charitylen%d",[charityIdString length]);
}
```